# How to update category of a clicked bar in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I can update the category of x-axis in Highcharts. But I need to update the category or enable the category of clicked Bar.

Comment: can u show us u code so far

Comment: @sakir http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-rotated-labels/ refer this link for code.I disabled all category initially.If I click any bar  enable the category of clicked element only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to render all labels, but in callback hide them by setting opacity as 0. As a result we have labels (physically) but not visible.

```
$.each(chart.xAxis[0].ticks, function (i, tick) {
        if(tick.label) {
            tick.label.attr({
                opacity: 0
            });
        }
    });
```

Next step is catch click action on point and show/hide label.

```
  plotOptions: {
            series: {
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click:function(){

                            var x = this.x,
                                chart = this.series.chart,
                                ticks = chart.xAxis[0].ticks,
                                currentLabel = ticks[x].label;


                            if(currentLabel.opacity === 0) {
                                currentLabel.attr({
                                    opacity: 1
                                });
                            } else {
                                currentLabel.attr({
                                    opacity: 0
                                });
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ojjajck9/2/